# Cannot update variable used as prerequisites

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to update a variable and then used it as prerequisite for a rule
My code is as following:

```
OBJ:=origin
  
.PHONY: all update_variables compile_obj

all: update_variables compile_obj
        @echo "rule: $@"

update_variables:
        @echo "rule: $@"
        @echo "     updating OBJ"
        $(eval OBJ=updated)

compile_obj: $(OBJ)
        @echo "rule: $@"
        @echo "     OBJ seen from inside rule is $(OBJ)"
        @echo "     OBJ seen as prerequisite is $^" 

$(OBJ):
        @touch origin
```

in this code, I intend for "all" to run "update_variables" first, where $(OBJ) is updated and then compile_obj, where $(OBJ) is used as a prerequisite

After "make all", following lines printed out on my terminal:

```
rule: update_variables
     updating OBJ
rule: compile_obj
     OBJ seen from inside rule is updated
     OBJ seen as prerequisite is origin
rule: all
```

It seems to me that the rule order is what I wanted but $(OBJ) value is unexpected in rule "compile_obj":
in the recipe, $(OBJ) is seen as "updated" but $^ is still "origin" while I though they would be the same

I'm still learning make, can you please kindly instruct me why updated value of  $(OBJ) are not seen in prerequisite?

Comment: There is no way this can work.  Makefiles are not procedural languages, like a program where you start at the top and "compile" each item as you go.  Makefile processing proceeds in two distinct phases: first ALL the makefiles are parsed and converted into an internal graph of targets and prerequisites.  All the variables that are required to construct that graph (variables in targets and prerequisites) are fully expanded at that time.  Second, the graph is walked and the needed recipes are run.  The variables required to run the recipes are expanded at that time.

Comment: This means that the `$(OBJ)` in the prerequisites list is expanded to whatever value it has in the first phase, then the `$(eval ...)` is run in the second phase when the recipe is run... but that has no effect on the values expanded in the first phase: those were already expanded.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. May I know:
- where can I read more about the phases?
- If I need to modify variables as prerequisite for next recipe, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html  Info on when variables are expanded: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html

Comment: There is no way to do that.  However, there **is** very likely to be a way to do what you really are trying to do.  But since you haven't explained why you really want to do this and have only asked this specific question all we can say is, "no you can't do that".

Comment: Hi, just as you said, I got used to precedural languages ><. I am trying to build .o file from .c file, but because .c file is scattered in project, I try to get paths through a "function" before the compiling recipe.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: https://xyproblem.info/  It might be best to close this question and ask a new question about what you actually want to do.  You need to explain what you mean by _.c files is scattered_ and why it's not sufficient to list sources directly or to use normal `wildcard` etc. to locate source files, and how complex an operation it is to find the source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MadScientist mention,prerequisite is expanded at the very beginning, so updating it in recipes dont really work. I will close the question now, thank you all :)